# Set embedded field's text in XML using Java

Tags: java, xml, soap

I receive an object of XML in Java and I should call to one WS and modify several datas.

```
<xml> 
  <tag1>xml value 1</tag1>
  <tag2>xml value 2</tag2>
  <tag3>xml value 3</tag3>
  <tag4>
      <es>xml es value 4</es>
      <en>xml en value 4</en>
  </tag4>
  <tag5>
      <es>xml es value 5</es>
      <en>xml en value 5</en>
  </tag5>
</xml>
```

I'm using the following code to change the  to new value:

```
.getElementsByTagNameNS("*" ,"tag3").item(0).getFirstChild().setTextContent("new value")
```

If I want to change the tag "en" in the  I can't do that because I have two tag with the same name child of different other tags.

Anyone know how can I do that?

Comment: the xml is a example. don't mind if a tag its not good close its only a error typo.

Answer (score 1):

You missed close tag.close the en tag properly then set value

```
<tag 5>
  <es>xml es value 5</es>
  <en>xml en value 5</en>
</tag5>
```

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned above, your XML structure is not correct you missed to close your 'en' tag on 'tag 5':

```
<xml> 
  <tag 1>xml value 1</tag 1>
  <tag 2>xml value 2</tag 2>
  <tag 3>xml value 3</tag 3>
  <tag 4>
      <es>xml es value 4</es>
      <en>xml en value 4</en>
  </tag 4>
  <tag 5>
      <es>xml es value 5</es>
      <en>xml en value 5</en>
  </tag 5>
</xml>
```